# Why aren’t people in Ohio allowed to order a bottle of scotch?

Tags: spirits, laws

If you check websites like Drizly, it seems that people in Ohio aren’t allowed to order a bottle of scotch. Why is that?

Edit: The delivery services I’m referring to (e.g. Drizly) are a delivery service like food deliveries, not UPS or FedEx. They aren’t distributors, and they don’t carry the packages across state lines — they’re just local drivers that pickup and deliver a bottle from the nearest liquor store.

Also, they deliver beer, so I doubt it has to do with minors.

As an additional note, they deliver scotch in the state I’m from, so it seems to be something unique to this state, like some kind of law (which I have been unable to find).

Comment: I’m not an expert, but I believe many states strictly control the distribution of alcoholic beverages especially from out of state sources. All alcohol must go through licensed distributors. The rationale is to keep alcohol out of hands of minors.

Comment: Are you saying that they won't deliver scotch, but they *will* deliver bourbon?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though there were certain restrictions on home delivery of spirits up until just a few days ago, actually.

"Home delivery," being the same as food-service-home-delivery, and different from having alcohol mailed to your residence, oddly...

> Ohio
>
> ALLOWED. Ohio has relaxed laws for alcohol delivery fulfillment but
> **prohibits producers that make more than 250,000 gallons of alcohol
> from delivery to consumers. You will need to become compliant for
> mailing alcohol to consumers in Ohio**, as well as be aware of local and
> city laws.
>
> https://2ndkitchen.com/breweries/how-to-ship-alcohol/

Again, this has apparently changed as of 2021 since [Ohio Governor Mike DeWine signed a bill allowing home delivery of liquor](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/governor-mike-dewine-signs-bill-allowing-home-delivery-of-liquor-revising-existing-sales-provisions/ar-BB1cAxqC).

So, look for this site and other services to update their respective catalogs and available products very soon - just in time for the next quarantine, no doubt...